# How should I set the permissions on files to be served via apache to disallow access by people with login accounts on the web server?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, permissions

I have some static files that I would like to serve via Apache to a website which uses basic authentication to restrict access. In addition, I want to be able to prevent people with login accounts on the web server from accessing these files.

What's the best way to achieve this? The simplest thing would be to have the restricted files owned by the web server account ("apache", in my case, as I'm running on Fedora). However, [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=540621) suggests that allowing the web server user to own anything in the www root is a bad idea from a security perspective:

> As a general rule, no mechanism should
>   exist that might theoretically allow
>   your apache server to write to
>   anything on your system, unless there
>   is simply no other way of achieving a
>   particular effect you happen to want.
>
> The most effective ways of ensuring this include... [n]ot doing anything silly ... eg allowing your web server user to own anything in the www root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use group permissions, set your files with RW access for the user you want and set access to RO for the group apache belong to.

Comment: Right, the user account that owns the file will have access (you can make it root if you really want).  Also, if you really don't want users on the box to be able to read the file you need to make sure that there are no users in the group apache belongs to (which there normally wouldn't be, but you should check).

Comment: Do not forget to set directory permissions the same way (disable the write permission for apache and read/write/execute permissions for others)